# use single method to calculate age from multiple input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is my code to calculate age.I am using same method for multiple inputs in `ng-change`.
 but I can bind age for only one input field using single method.
Why don't I use single method to bind result data for multiple inputs based on model name?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
   
     $scope.calculateAge = function (fieldName,value) {debugger
        var birthDay =value;
        var DOB = new Date(birthDay);
        var today = new Date();
        var age = today.getTime() - DOB.getTime();
        age = Math.floor(age / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
       
        fieldName=age;
        //$scope.data1.age=age;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
<div>
    <input type="date" ng-model="data1.dob" ng-change="calculateAge(data1.age,data1.dob)"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data1.age"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="date" ng-model="data2.dob" ng-change="calculateAge(data2.age,data2.dob)"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data2.age"/>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

I know I can to do by passing input Id's. but am trying it for model name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass references of your `data` in the method and modify that.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
   
     $scope.calculateAge = function (data) {debugger
        var birthDay = data.dob;
        var DOB = new Date(birthDay);
        var today = new Date();
        var age = today.getTime() - DOB.getTime();
        age = Math.floor(age / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
        data.age = age;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
<div>
    <input type="date" ng-model="data1.dob" ng-change="calculateAge(data1)"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data1.age"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="date" ng-model="data2.dob" ng-change="calculateAge(data2)"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data2.age"/>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just try this:     `$scope[fieldName] =age;`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

     $scope.calculateAge = function (fieldName,value) {debugger
        var birthDay =value;
        var DOB = new Date(birthDay);
        var today = new Date();
        var age = today.getTime() - DOB.getTime();
        age = Math.floor(age / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));

        //fieldName=age;
        $scope[fieldName] =age;// $scope[value] is eq. to $scope.data2.age
    }
})
```